# Is there a gdb (or similar) frontend that will show the program stack visually?

Tags: memory, gdb, stack, ddd-debugger

Basically, I'm looking for something where I can break execution and then see a visual representation of the stack in memory.  DDD doesn't have this as far as I can tell.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "visual representation of the stack"?

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/93/Stack_Overflow_3.png

Comment: @Justin that link is full of brokenness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Green Hills debugger, MULTI, has a display that will show you all of the function calls on the stack and their functions parameters. I'm not sure if this is what you meant by visual or not. I'm not aware of any debugger or tool that will show the hex dump of a stack and highlight it in a graphical way.

-djhaus